# Basic string error in python

Tags: python, string

Question:
Write a function called censor that takes two strings, text and word, as input. It should return the text with the word you chose replaced with asterisks.

My code:

```
def censor(text, word):
    t=text
    w=word
    l2=len(word)
    res=""
    p=["*" * l2]
    str1="".join(p)
    for i in range(0,len(text)):
        if t[i] in text and t[i] not in word:
            res=res+t[i]+str1
    return res
```

for a input of ("hey hey hey", "hey"); the correct result is three groups of three *** each. my code gives two groups of 3 stars each only. Any idea why?

Comment: `if t[i] in text and t[i] not in word` checks if the character at index `i` of `t` is in `text`. I don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much easier  split and either replace the word with `"*" *` the len of the word to replace or just keep the word:

```
def censor(text, word):
    l2 = len(word)
    p = "*" * l2
    return " ".join([ch if ch != word  else p for ch in text.split(" ")])
```

`str1="".join(p)`  os not needed you can simply use `p = "*" * l2`

If you use `str.replace` as suggested in other answers  partial matches will be replaced so `heys -> ***s`

Also we explicitly pass a delimiter to split so when we rejoin we will keep the original string length intact.

If you want to strip punctuation before comparing then use `rstrip`:

```
from string import punctuation

def censor(text, word):
    l2 = len(word)
    p = "*" * l2
    return " ".join([ch if ch.rstrip(punctuation) != word  else p for ch in text.split(" ")])

In [3]: censor("foo! foobar","foo")
Out[3]: '*** foobar'
```

Comment: Yeah +1, `essex` (a version of OpenStack) will become `es***`

Comment: @BhargavRao, yes, but  judging by the downvote some rocket scientist disagrees ;)

Comment: Or just to balance ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao, maybe so, I won't lose any sleep over it either way :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Padriac! This was a question on codeacademy. I tried it for a while, and then asked around here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SushantPasumarty, no prob. I presumed you only wanted to match actual words.

Answer (score 2):

Use the batteries... seriously :-)

```
def censor(text, word):
    r = "*" * len(word)
    return text.replace(word, r)

print censor("hey hey hey", "hey")
```

Test:

```
python replace.py
*** *** ***
```

Documentation for  [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

Comment: try `censor("heys  hey hey", "hey")`

Comment: "***s *** ***" -- so what? :) Did Sushant Pasumarty specify what should happen in this case? What do you think is the expected output in this case?

Comment: then you are not replacing a word that matches you are replacing a partial match which is not the same thing ;)

Comment: I know, but I just wanted to point out that the OP did not specify what *should* happen in such a case. You cannot dictate that *your* specification is the right one, which is why down-voting these solutions is inappropriate.

Comment: Well a word is a word. a partial word is not a word so it is pretty clear. *It should return the text with the word you chose replaced with asterisks.*

Comment: Counter argument: `censor(text, "hey")` specifies that "hey" is the word to be replaced. Now, you surely agree that "heys" is not equal to the word "hey". So, why would you want to replace it at all? A very logical argument, too, perfectly fitting the OPs definition. Conclusion: he/she did not *precisely* state what the goal is.

Comment: lol you are totally missing the point. Your last comment makes no sense in relation to what I have explained. Your code replaces anywhere word appears at all.

Comment: I know how my code behaves, and my last argument was in favor of your solution, so I think *you* are missing the point :P | A partial match should either be partially replaced or not replaced at all or the entire word containing the partial match should be replaced. Which of the three paths to take? OP has to tell. That is my point. :) -- Fun fun, no offense.

Comment: John, sorry if I  didn't specify that censor("heys hey hey", "hey") should only censor hey. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `string.replace` method:

```
def censor(text, word):
    new = len(word) * '*' # as many asterisks as characters in word
    return text.replace(word, new) # return censored string
```

Now we should test the `censor` method:

```
>>> print censor('Holy crap.', 'crap') # prints Holy ****.
```

Answer (score 0):

All that you're trying to do is replace stuff in a string. There's a method for that:

```
def censor(text, word):
    return text.replace(word, "*" * len(word))

In [2]: censor("hey hey hey", "hey")
Out[2]: '*** *** ***'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler than you've made it--

```
def censor(text, word):
  p = '*' * len(word)
  return text.replace(word,p)
```